# Npm run build generates wrong paths

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli-3

To deploy my `Vue Cli 3` project I did `npm run build`, however `index.html` in the new `dist/` folder contains wrong paths like this:

```
<link href=/css/app.35dee36a.css
<link href=/js/app.826dde09.js
```

as a result I get those in the console:

```
Failed to load resource - http://my_site.com/js/app.826dde09.js
```

It should be `http://my_site.com/timelog/js`, not `http://my_site.com/js`.

I tried to specify URLs in `package.json` by adding `"baseUrl": "http://my_site.com/timelog/", "homepage": "http://my_site.com/timelog/",` but it doesn't change anything.

What is causing this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: The built version is supposed to be run on a webserver with an actual domain name.

Comment: I have a cheap shared hosting package, I don't think I can run something like that on their server. Are you sure this is the issue and there's no workaround?

Comment: If you want to develop, run `npm run serve` and go to `localhost:8080` or whatever the port is that it runs on. `npm run build` is a production build and does not work if you open `index.html` through a `file:///` link. As long as you have ftp or sftp access to your server, and have any domain name, you should be able to transfer anything in the `dist` folder to the folder that serves as your public_html folder. That would allow you to either access `yourdomain.com/index.html` or `yourdomain.com` if any rewriting is enabled.

Comment: Thanks, you're correct, however the paths are still wrong. I edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solve this by creating a `vue.config.js` file at the root of my project with the following content:

```
module.exports = {
  baseUrl: '/timelog/'
}
```

(to make internal links work as well see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56199917/871404))

Comment: It seems that `baseUrl` has been replaced by `publicPath`. This answer helped me anyway, thank You.