# How to get internal links' URLs right with npm run build?

Tags: vue.js, npm, production-environment, vue-cli

My app is hosted in a subfolder: `my_site.com/my_app/`. Although I'm using a `vue.config.js` file specifying the path of my app on the server (`publicPath: '/my_app/'`, the internal links in my app are still wrong:

Instead of pointing to `my_site/my_app/destination` they point to `my_site/destination`.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the internal links are handled by Vue router.

changing the `base` option in Vue router should solve your problem.

https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base

sample

```
new VueRouter({
    base: '/my_app/', 
    routes: [...]
});
```